# Generate custom icon font

Tags: css, angular, webfonts

We'd like to generate a custom icon font and use it like this one: https://github.com/marella/material-icons

We have used fantasticon to generate the woff files and it works fine, if we set the icon name as a style class. But we want to use it the same way we use the other icons, so putting the name of the icon as content of a span instead of a style class. Is there any option we are missing while generating the font?

This is what fantasticon generated:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Company Icons";
src: url("./Company Icons.eot?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("./Company Icons.woff2?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b") format("woff2"),
url("./Company Icons.woff?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b") format("woff");
}

i\[class^="icon-"\]:before, i\[class\*=" icon-"\]:before {
font-family: Company Icons !important;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal !important;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
\-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
\-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-weiter:before {
content: "\\f101";
}
```

This is what we have additionally written to make it usable in spans:

```
@import "Company Icons.css";

@font-face {
font-family: "Company Icons";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-display: block;
src: url("./Company Icons.eot?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("./Company Icons.woff2?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b") format("woff2"),
url("./Company Icons.woff?b5a07dabf1643d1512d57b5333f6d08b") format("woff");
}

.company-icons {
font-family: "Company Icons", sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1;
letter-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: normal;
direction: ltr;
\-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
\-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-feature-settings: "liga";
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, what exactly you mean by _"putting the name of the icon as content of a span instead of a style class"_?

Comment: Sure, like this: <span class="company-icons">weiter</span> instead of this: <span class="company-icons weiter"></span>

Comment: Then your font would have to support _ligatures_ - that's multiple characters represented by a single glyph. I doubt your font supports this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint, will check it out. We opened the font in fontforge and saw "weiter" set for our icon. We will investigate if fantasticon has some ligature option.